# Self Organizing maps Vs k-means

Tags: k-means, self-organizing-maps

Does anyone know how well does Self Organizing Maps(SOM) compare to k-means? I believe usually in the color space,such as RGB, SOM is a better method to cluster colors together as there is overlap in the color space between visually different colors (http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html). Are there cases where k-means outperforms SOM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K-means is a specialisation of SOM, I believe. You can *construct* ideal cases for it, I'm sure. I think computational speed is its major advantage -- when you have incrementally improving AI algorithms, sometimes more iterations of a worse algorithm gives better performance than fewer iterations of a bettwer, slower algorithm.

It all depends on the data. You never know until you run it.

Answer (score -1):

K-means is a subset of Self-Organizing Maps (SOM).  K-means is strictly an average n-dimensional vector of the n-space neighbors.  SOM is similar but the idea is to make a candidate vector closer to the matching vector and increase the difference with surrounding vectors by perturbing them; the perturbation decreases (kernel width) with distance; that is where the Self-Organizing part of the name comes from.

Comment: this doesn't sounds right to me. I would consider SOM as a more restrictive version of K-means (not the other way around).

Answer (score -2):

Self Organizing Maps create a 2-dimensional output. k-means is multi-dimensional.
SOMs operate in a discretized representation (grid). SOMs use a more local rule (neighborhood function).
k-means is more widely used as a clustering algorithm.

Comment: SOMs do not necessarily create 2D output. Most implementations do, but there also exist SOMs with 3D lattices. SOMs usually map high dimensional codebook vectors onto lower-dimensional vectors in a lower-dimensional lattice, which is not limited to 2D, 3D, etc by any means.